# Implement IsNotNullAndGreaterThanZero Extension Method using Generics

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, extension-methods

I have an Extension Method as mentioned below.Is there a way were I can make it work in a generic way.For int?,decimal?,long?,double?.Or is there a limitation in the way 0(zero) is compared for different numeric data type?

```
public static bool IsNotNullAndGreaterThanZero(this decimal? value)
{
return (value ?? 0M) > 0M;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
public static bool IsNotNullAndGreaterThanDefault<T>(this T? value)
    where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    return value != null && value.Value.CompareTo(default(T)) > 0;
}
```

That uses the fact that for most value types, the default value is the "natural zero".

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) to do this:

```
public static bool IsNotNullAndGreaterThanZero<T>(this T? value)
     where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    return value != null && value.ToDecimal() > 0M;
}
```

The basic value types such as int/long/double all implement `IConvertible`, which would allow this to work.